# Why is the fourier transform of the autocovariance function only integrated from $-\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, fourier-transform, time-series, stationary-processes

in several time series texts like Shumway, the Fourier transform of the autocovariance function is integrated only over frequencies from $-\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{2}$.
I do not understand why it doesn't integrate over $[-\infty, \infty]$ but I vaguely remember something from my numerical methods course about the interval and periodicity. (Could it be that this assumes a period of $1$?)

Could someone explain why we don't have to consider $f$ outside of $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ here:

$$ \gamma(h) = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{i2 \pi hf}df$$ where $f$ is the frequency and $h$ the lag?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: For a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ the (if it exists) Fourier transform is usually intended to be the [DTFT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform). The resulting transform is periodic, and the inverse is over an interval which length depends on the transform convention used.

Comment: @Snoop thanks a lot, this is what I understood as well, I am not so good at reading so I went over the chapter again in Shumway and Chatfield and they both don't mention the interval, I guess its to trivial to mention.